# Embedded python security considerations

Tags: python, c++, security, boost-python

I'm embedding Python 3.4 in a C++ application. As an overview (or provide details if you can), what security considerations should I be thinking about if a user of the system is able to submit arbitrary Python code for execution?

There are two cases:

1. A single script is accepted which auto imports a module and provides an API to get data out and put stuff in (no SQL is involved so SQL injection isn't a thing).
2. An archive is accepted which is supposed to contain a full Python app which implements a few interfaces but is also allowed to have a setup.py and/or requirements.txt to have app dependencies installed from an SCM or PyPi. No dependency limits have yet been imposed.

Operationally, the "normal" use case for this was originally that it'd be locked down behind a firewall so only "trusted" users would ever have the permissions to do both 1 and 2.

Recently however, there has been talk of widening the scope amongst ourselves (giving access to customers). Initially it seemed like a good idea, the possibilities that it opens are super attractive but alarm bells have been going off saying this has bad idea written all over it.

That however is just an intuition, I'm not a security expert and can only enumerate a few obvious reasons it'd be an issue.

So is there a way to expose both 1 and 2 above (but mostly 1) to customers, in a secure away? What steps (if any) could be taken to limit the scope of what the arbitrary Python we accept could do?

I've just come across [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which, from my glance so far seems to do a similar thing, currently going through their code to see how they've done it but thought I'd ask in the meanwhile.

Comment: PyPy is able to run code in a secure sandbox (see [here](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sandbox.html)). It can be [embedded into C/C++](http://pypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/embedding.html) though I have no idea whether combining the two things is supported...

Comment: You cant run abitrary python code securely. Hackers will always find a way

Comment: Important questions are: Who has access to your service? What is the likelyhood of someone who has access actually wanting to cause trouble/hack your system? What data will be available if those with access DOES bypass your system? Will your business go under if someone bypasses the system, or will there be financial consequences for third parties? The answer of how much security you need will depend highly on these questions. NOTHING is 100% secure - I'm constantly remembering the story of the "new expensive computer, new alarm, new door - thieves broke in using a digger through a brick wall"